# Bundle.main.url Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, core-data, entity

i am implementing add to cart functionality in my app and i am create entity name cart but when i am run the app and its giving me crash

> **Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** and
>
> **Printing description of modelURL: expression produced error: error: /var/folders/sm/kfj_nc256ys4gmxm495_fkrm0000gn/T/expr16-0d7e17..swift:1:65:
>   error: use of undeclared type 'Foundation'
>   Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer(bitPattern:
>   0x1026a0280)!.pointee)**

also getting error like this now will show my code

```
 lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "MYAPP.Notepad" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "RushabhJewels_1", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "RushabhJewels")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()
    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

please tell me how to solve this

```
  lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "RushabhJewels_1", withExtension: "momd")
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL!)!
    }()
```

i am getting crash here i found modelurl nil

Comment: Can you attach an image/snapshot of the code(and that particular line) at which the app is crashing?

Comment: yes sure wait i will attech

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi i won't allow to attach image because i don't have enough reputation

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi please tell me whats the issue in my code

Comment: Atleast highlight the line at which it is crashing

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi please check i updated my question

Comment: Check for any typos (i.e. spelling mistakes) and check if the resource _actually exists_ in your project . To check , _Your Project_ -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources , expand then menu and check if the resource (RushabhJewels_1. momd) is present there

Comment: no xcdatamodel is not in copy bundle resources

Comment: but when i add into this i am getting error like this 
Showing All Messages
:-1: unexpected duplicate task: DataModelCompile /Users/hemshub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RushabhJewels-glqdbijxahapszbninyuwfhfgkxz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RushabhJewels.app/ /Users/hemshub/Desktop/RushabhJewels/RushabhJewels/RushabhJewels.xcdatamodel (in target 'RushabhJewels')

Comment: please tell me why this error come when i add that in copy bundle resources

Comment: Refer to this article :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964681/build-is-producing-a-momd-in-the-bundle-that-is-missing-the-mom-file

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600312/how-to-get-path-of-momd-file-in-core-data

Comment: and this one as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536414/cant-find-momd-file-core-data-problems

Comment: Thanks to All now my code works fine